# I have a large number of files I want to rename with increasing numbers and don't appear to have the rename function

Tags: file, sed, renaming

I've been having a good dig around and found out about "rename" and "sed", I'm not very computer proficient, but I've had a go at what I have found.
So far - I'm able to use sed to find what I want to search for, but I can't work out how to replace with what I'm actually looking for (hopefully that makes sense).

So - the scenario:
I have 5000 files in 3 batches (2000, 2000 and 1000), the program that generates them always numbers from 1 - x, so time_step_1 ... 
I need the files to be consecutive (so not the batches beginning at 1)

I tried:
`ls time_step_*|sed 's/[0-9]\(.*\)/mv & time_step_\1+2001/'`
and it printed:

```
time_step_mv 10.txt time_step_0.txt+2001
time_step_mv 11.txt time_step_1.txt+2001
time_step_mv 12.txt time_step_2.txt+2001
time_step_mv 13.txt time_step_3.txt+2001
time_step_mv 14.txt time_step_4.txt+2001
time_step_mv 15.txt time_step_5.txt+2001
time_step_mv 1.txt time_step_.txt+2001
time_step_mv 2.txt time_step_.txt+2001
time_step_mv 3.txt time_step_.txt+2001
time_step_mv 4.txt time_step_.txt+2001
time_step_mv 5.txt time_step_.txt+2001
time_step_mv 6.txt time_step_.txt+2001
time_step_mv 7.txt time_step_.txt+2001
time_step_mv 8.txt time_step_.txt+2001
time_step_mv 9.txt time_step_.txt+2001
```

but the file names themselves haven't changed
I have managed this same output a few times over.

I think I understand about piping and "saving" characters etc., but like I said, not very computer proficient and as much as anything I'm getting confused about the terminology on the various posts I have read.

All help very much appreciated

Comment: Are the files all in the same directory? Or are there 2000 files in one directory, 2000 in another and 1000 in a third directory?

Comment: They're all in different directories, the first 2000 come up fine, it's the 3000 following that I'm looking to change - that said, the program is running in Windows and I'm just shuffling it across to Linux, so it can be arranged however.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So...

First off, let me just point you at the [ParsingLS](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) page in the Bash wiki.  It highlights the dangers of trusting the output of the `ls` command.  Which isn't to say you shouldn't do it, but you should *only* do it if you're aware of the dangers. :)

Some basic things:

- `sed` is not a programming language, it doesn't know how to do math.
- Anything you match in your regular expression needs to be accounted for in the output, even "implied" things at the beginning and end of the expression.  That's why you have your `mv` embedded in the output string.

You said:

```
 ls time_step_* | sed 's/[0-9]\(.*\)/mv & time_step_\1+2001/'
```

This has the effect of taking a filename like `time_step_12.txt` and replacing ONLY the **`12.txt`** with your replacement string.  Notwithstanding the fact that sed can't do math, the regex that you really want to use here has account for the WHOLE bunch of input text.  For example, in bash:

```
 ls time_step_* | sed -r 's/^(.*_)([0-9]+)(.*)/mv & \1\2\3/'
```

The result is a set of commands which you could pipe through sh (or bash) by adding `| sh` to the end of the line to execute the commands once you verify that they are correct.  Note the `-r` option which in many implementations tells sed to interpret the regex as ERE instead of BRE.  If this doesn't work for you (because you're using an older unix, SVR4, etc), say so and we can convert the regex to BRE.

I will point out that this is NOT a good way to solve this problem, most notably because, as I said, sed doesn't do math.  If you want to add an integer to a component of the filename, then you need to process it with something that DOES do math.  Like bash.

You could use sed to pull out part of the data, then process it in a simple `while` loop:

```
for file in time_step_*.txt; do
  number=${file%.txt}          # strip off the suffix
  number=${number#time_step_}  # strip off the prefix
  if [[ $number -gt 0 ]]; then
    mv "$file" "time_step_$[number+2000].txt"
  else
    echo "ERROR: $file couldn't be processed" >&2
  fi
done
```

This has the advantage of doing everything except the `mv` inside the shell, so no unnecessary external processes are launched.  Of course, your sed pipeline wouldn't have caused MUCH of a problem.  And if you wanted to (bearing the ParsingLS link above in mind), you could use sed to reduce the bash pattern matching, making this portable to non-Bash shells.  Without error checking, it might look like this:

```
ls time_step_*.txt | sed -r 's/^(.*_)([0-9]+)(.*)/\2 &/' | while read number file; do
  mv "$file" "time_step_$((number+2000)).txt"
done
```

This works by converting a filename like `time_step_12.txt` into a string like `12 time_step_12.txt` so that the two separate words can be read into separate variables by `while`.  Note that you *will* have failures if the number turns out not to be purely numeric.

Hope this was educational.  :-)

Comment: What a fantastic answer!  Thank you for all the description of what things are doing and their capabilities - it certainly explains why a few of my hamfisted attemps with sed and grep may have not worked in the past...  I don't know what you mean by ERE and BRE, but the code you have presented above works (so i think that means I am in ERE).

Comment: Thanks, glad it was useful! BRE and ERE are "Basic" and "Extended" Regular Expression. On any unix system (including OSX), you should be able to run [`man re_format`](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=re_format) to learn about both of these.

Answer (score 1):

this should work for the second batch, then do +3000 for the third

```
for f in time_step_*; do 
   n=${f%.*}; n=${n##*_}; ((n+=2000));
   mv "$f" time_step_$n.txt
done
```

Comment: Consider adding double quotes around `"$f"` in the `mv` command.

Comment: mkay, put some "s to be safe, and cleaned up a bit